# Comparing string to a letter, incompatible parameter

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

I'm having trouble with this bit of code:

```
char myword[] = "ABC\0";
   // for loop for length of array 
   for (int i = 0; i<strlen(myword); i++) { 
    if (strcmp(myword[i], 'A') == 0) {...
```

which should check if the letter which is i is equal to A. Have tried entering the ABC as different letters but the error:

> Error: Argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *" in "main.cpp"

keeps appearing.

Comment: C is not C++ - don't spam tags. Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Your string is 5 characters long, with two `\0` characters. I'm guessing that's not what you had in mind.

Comment: You're using strcmp to compare individual characters. strcmp is for comparing arrays, or strings, of characters

Comment: Listen to your compiler's warning.

Answer (score 2):

The `strcmp()` function compares *strings*, not individual characters. You can compare characters using the built-in `==` operator:

```
char myword[] = "ABC"; // (1)
// for loop for length of array 
for (int i = 0; i<strlen(myword); i++) { 
    if (myword[i] == 'A') { ...  }
}
```

Incidentally, there's no need to manually add the null-terminator on line (1) -- the language will add this for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (strcmp(myword[i], 'A') == 0) {
```

`strcmp` is there for comparing **strings**, not single characters. Just try comparing the characters directly, i.e.

```
if (myword[i] == 'A') {
```